# UICollectionView Cells do not animate movement

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

When I initiate movement for my collectionView cells, the cells do not move. They move only when I pan my finger over another cell. So if I initiate a movement by pressing one of my cells and then pan, the cells do not track my finger. The only time animation occurs is when my finger pans over another cell. At that point the animation is just the reordering. Bonus: One I end my gesture (lift up my finger) the current cell I was moving around disappears from view. I am using a custom flow layout

Comment: did you manage to solve this one buddy?

Comment: Yes I did thank you, I did something completely different using UIView Snapshots and moving those around

Answer (score 0):

My custom flowLayout is stopping the animation. In my custom layout I set the frames of my cells (their attribute frames) to a specific position that is hardcoded in my layout. When the long press gesture is initiated I have to change my attributes somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update your attributes. Just make sure you are overriding these methods in your custom layout:

`layoutAttributesForElements`

`layoutAttributesForItem`

`layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView`